# iOS SDK 5.0 (xcode 4.x)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, upgrade

basic question regarding xcode 4.2 and iOS SDK5

I have an older MAC and really can't use anything higher- if I made an app for this target, will it be rejected?

Does the newer SDK 7.0 have to be the target? will the app run on newer versions (like it would in Android)

I looked around but seem to find mixed answers- just seeing what my options are.

Comment: I think you mean "the new SDK 8.0", not "7.0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use at least Xcode 5 to be able to distribute your apps to the App Store. In a few months, the minimum requirement will likely become Xcode 6.